# Append events to eventstore

Tags: cqrs, axon

We are using axon framework version 3.4.2 and found a bug inside our code. The bug relates to a missing event which was not published. The solution is to fix the code but this would not fix the event store and views.

My question is how would one fix this? We thought of appending the events to the event store (we use a JDBC event store), but without the correct data, the new events would not be processed. The best would be to do it in the application by publishing the event in axon and let axon handle all the details, but this is a once-off, correcting action.

Is there any way of "injecting" a once-off event into axon?

Comment: No direct Axon experience, My understanding, in general eventing, this would be a specific correcting command and event such as PulledSomeMissingOrderInfoFromShopify (e.g. we forgot to capture the customer remote IP and user agent and isMobile), .. The generated event could be enriched from previous data (all the other information already in your read layer from the original event ShopifyOrderCreated), and the event handling could rewrite the views, publish something on the event bus, or whatever needs done.. etc..

Answer (score 1):

The comment which Matt shared is conceptually what you should do.
Thus, to resolve the issue you unintendedly introduced, you should produce a compensation action, aka a command. This command will be handled in your command model, will validate the model's state and publish the desired event.

Added, I am assuming this event of your should originate from an Aggregate, correct?
In Axon terms, that means you want to publish a *domain event* rather than a regular *event*.

Although you can publish events on the `EventBus` or store in the `EventStore` directly, it is rather complicated to make those *domain events* through that process.
Thus, as I started off with and what Matt Freeman commented on your question, a compensating action would be the way to go, with or without Axon.

---

Last note, know that Axon 4.2 is already out for some time now. Although Axon 3 will still under go bug fixes, none of these have occurred in the last year. Simply put, there is no active development on Axon 3. Migrating to a more recent version would thus be beneficial for your project.